# Sort 2D array based on user provided indices

Tags: c#, sorting

In python there is a functionality (numpy.take) to sort arrays within an array, for example if I have an array (3x3):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3],[7,9,10],[3, 5,6]]
```

and I have an array of set indices

```
indices = [2, 0, 1]
```

the result shall be

```
array([[ 3,  5,  6], [ 1,  2,  3], [ 7,  9, 10]]).
```

Are there any direct approach methods/ functions as these in C# where I can pass in a jagged array and produce the same output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, but you can achieve the same thing with Linq

```
var a = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 7, 9, 10 }, new[] { 3, 5, 6 } };
var indices = new [] { 2, 0, 1 };
var sorted = indices.Select(i => a[i]).ToArray();
foreach(var s in sorted) Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", s));
```

Note this does not check that your indices are all in range.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with LINQ:

```
var a = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 7, 9, 10 }, new[] { 3, 5, 6 } };
var indices = new[] { 2, 0, 1};

var result = indices
    .Select(i => a[i])
    .ToArray();
```

Or `.ToList()` if you prefer lists.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `Array.Sort(keys, values)` - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = new[]
{
    new[] {1, 2, 3},
    new[] {7, 9, 10},
    new[] {3, 5, 6}
};

var indices = new[] {2, 0, 1};

var sortedArray = a.SortEx(indices);
```

Where `SortEx` is

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T[][] SortEx<T>(this T[][] source, int[] indices)
    {
        return indices.Select(index => source[index]).ToArray();
    }
}
```

This assumes that the all the indices in the `indices` array are not out of bound in `a`.